# Android device stuck in a bootloop and there's nothing I can do about it

Tags: root-access

I have a Huawei smartphone, which unfortunately bricked and stuck in a bootloop when I flash Magisk. It even got stuck getting into recovery mode. Can't find its firmware for now (Nova 2i - RNE-L22). Factory reset / wipe data also doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Samsung Galaxy Tab A.  From the Internet I got the idea to disconnect the battery, then let the unit's memory discharrge overnight.

This was not as a recommendation from the Internet, just my idea.  Of course this involves opening the back cover and fiddling with the interior battery connector.  Both tasks are not for the timid craftsman (sorry person).  But with due care it is manageable.  Although it was just a trail, it did work.

When reassembled and booted into the service mode, it did not go into the auto boot loop.  It let me select the factory reset from the menu.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you unlocked your phone's bootloader? If you have you can flash a TWRP or CWM recovery for your phone, which would enable any custom ROMs to be flashed. Otherwise you have to request (or buy) an unlock code first.
It is very possible to find twrp recovery and custom ROMs for your device.
To search for results, key words "nova 2i twrp" or "nova 2i rom" may be used. If Google don't give enough results also try Baidu since most of Huawei users are in China. Your browser can translate pages into English. pages about how to flash recs and ROMs usually come with such search results.